# clustering using some constraints

Tags: r

I am trying to cluster / assign few items (say 200 destinations) to some sales managers (say 50 sales managers) such that the overall distance to be traveled by the managers is least. I am using k-means clustering. The answer I get is least distances but the the number of destinations assigned is not very uniform. One sales mgr is getting 10 destinations while the other is getting only 1 and others in between.

So I want to add a restriction that the maximum destination allowed should be say 6 so that no sales manager is getting more than 6 destinations. Any help on how to add this restriction?

```
D1=read.xlsx("brisbane.xlsx")
km <- kmeans(cbind(D1$lat, D1$lng), centers = 50,iter.max = 100000)
    scluster<-km$cluster
    centers<-km$centers
out1 <- cbind(D1, clusterNum = scluster)
write.csv(out1,"brisbaneout.csv")
write.csv(centers,"brisbanecenters.csv")
```

Comment: I think you want to set up a linear program and not do k-means. I would look at `lpSolve`. You want to minimize the total distance traveled, subject to: all salespeople have assignments, no salespeople get more than 6 assignments etc

Comment: that is correct. Let me try lpSolve then. Thanks for the comments

Comment: I also formulated the problem in excel (using solver ad-in) but the solver has limitation of 200 decision variables. I have say 50 cities and 200 destinations making it 10,000 decision variables. Can anyone please suggest if there is a way to implement the same in any other programming language.

Comment: Hi, @user11503300, did the below solution help with your issue?

Comment: No @MDEWITT, it did not :(  .. i am working on it still

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's a solution to a similar problem. In linear programming this kind of problem is called the "transportation" problem. It's NP hard meaning that the only real way to solve it is to run through every possible combination, but there have been heuristics to help solve these.

Here is a solution in R

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

# This is a random matrix of 50 salespeople over 200 locations
# This would really be your distance matrix for each person and town

locations <- matrix(runif(200*50, 1, 500), nrow = 50)

# For the row constraint you want each sales person to travel less than 600 miles
row.signs <- rep ("<", 50)
row.rhs <- rep(600, 50)

# You additionally want each site to be visited once
col.signs <- rep (">", 200)
col.rhs <- rep(1, 200)

# Now you can solve the problem and verify that it converged
# Here we are trying to minimize the distance traveled hence "min"
(result <- lp.transport (locations, "min", row.signs, 
                         row.rhs, col.signs, col.rhs))

# And the output is a matrix with a "1" for each salesperson to visit a specific city
solution <- result$solution
```

That's how I would solve it.